Calling stored procedure with Hibernate which multiple type of outputs
I have a stored procedure from my DBA team. Here is the stored procedure, and temp table created. All I want to know here, how to map the temp table to the output value while calling the procedure in Java?
Create or replace package body package_name IS
    procedure procedure_name (
Id IN Long,
sDate IN DATE,
eDate in DATE,
Ind OUT package_name.pkg_Type,
Sol OUT VARCHAR2)
BEGIN
query (NOTE : Obtaining the results from multiple Tables)
end

Create or replace package package_name AS TYPE typ IS RECORD(id Integer,Name String);
TYPE pkg_Type IS TABLE OF typ INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
PROCEDURE procedure_name(Id IN Long,sDate IN DATE,eDate in DATE,Ind OUT package_name.pkg_Type,Sol OUT VARCHAR2)


I believe the mapping of database data types to Java classes depends on the JDBC driver you are using. Pardon me, but I did not find that detail in your question. Did I miss something?

Stored procedures cannot be mapped to hibernate classes. It is not a real object you create. Leave the output to the duples that might have transformed to a real DTO.
